# Show that $([-1,1]^d, ||\cdot||_\infty)$ is totally bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I need to show that $([-1,1]^d, ||\cdot||_\infty)$ where $||\cdot||$ is the usual metric, is totally bounded. Apparently this is done in the following way:

Let $\epsilon >0$, fix $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$ and  let $I_n = \{-n, -n +1, ..., n-1, n\}$. Now $B_\epsilon(\frac{k_1}{n},...,\frac{k_d}{n}):k_1,...,k_2 \in I_n$ is a finite collection of balls with radius $\epsilon$ which has a union that contains $[-1,1]^d$.

**I have a couple of questions:**

- Why does this show that $([-1,1]^d, ||\cdot||_\infty)$ is totally bounded?
- What does $||\cdot||_\infty$ really mean? The usual metric is defined by setting $d(x, y) = ||x-y||$. However, I read that $||x|| = \sup_n|x_n|$. How does this define a norm? If I want to know whether $[-1,1]^d$ is totally bounded I need to check whether for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a finite number of points such that $[-1,1]^d \subset \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n}B_\epsilon(x_i)$, right? What would $B_\epsilon(x)$ be with $||\cdot||_\infty$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This shows that your set is totally bounded because it shows that, given any $\varepsilon>0$, your set is a subset of a finite union of open balls whose radius is $\varepsilon$.
- $\bigl\|(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\bigr\|_\infty=\max\bigl\{|x_k|\,|\,k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\bigr\}$. It is a norm because it satisfies all the conditions that you can read in a [definition of norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition). Under this norm, $B_\varepsilon\bigl((x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\bigr)$ is the set of all $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)$, such that $|x_k-y_k|<\varepsilon$, for each $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.